# Add a specific number to a hashed object in C#

Tags: c#, hash

In a program I need to evaluate lots of objects. The result of evaluation is a double.
for example

```
Object myObject = new Object(x,y,z);
double a = eval(myObject);
```

after this lots of other objects should be evaluated.
I want to avoid reevaluating same objects. So I need to add evaluated objects and the evaluation result to a hash structure.

for example something like this after first evaluation: -------> this is a pseudo code

```
myHash.add(myObject, a);

Object anotherObject = new Object(x,y,z);

if (myHash.find(anotherObject))
   double evaluationForAnotherObject = myHash.get(anotherObject);
```

any help would be highly welcomed

Comment: Memoization. See http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/26/function-memoization.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` can be used for such lookups:

```
Dictionary<object,double> dict=new Dictionary<object,double>();
if(dict.ContainsKey(obj))
  x=dict[obj];
```

It's important to use the correct equality comparer. For example on objects it uses referential equality by default. If your `TKey` type doesn't use the desired equality comparison you can supply an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` to the constructor of the dictionary.

As an alternative you can pass your function into a memoizer. It returns a new function which caches the result of earlier computations. AFAIK the `MiscUtil` library contains one.

```
Func<object,double> memoizingEval=Memoizer.Memoize(eval);
```

and then use `memoizingEval(obj)`

Comment: Shouldn't that be Dictionary<object, double>?